# What´s the point of SAPGuiSession.Sync

Tags: hp-uft

The documentation for SAPGUISession.Sync says:

> Instructs UFT to wait until the SAP GUI for Windows session is available.

Is this 1:1 comparable to Web add-on´s `Page.Sync`? If so, when should I call it? Do I have to call Sync...

- after each input sent to the SAP GUI?
- after each input sent to the SAP GUI if a server roundtrip takes place after this input is received? (How can I identify that one takes place?)
- after each context-changing input sent to the SAP GUI?
- only once after launching the SAP session?

I haven´t had a chance to use the Windows-SAP Support in UFT yet, that´s why I find the documentation to be rather sparse.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAP´s Sync works just as Web´s Sync, but one important difference is:

While Page.Sync is often no guarantee that the app really is idle when Page.Sync Returns, for SAP applications, SAPSession.Sync´s returning does indeed guarantee this.

So whenever the SAP Client is doing Server roundtrips, SAPSession.Sync is a very save way of obtaining synchronization (i.e. awaiting SAP client´s idle state).

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it's the same as web's `Sync`, there's usually no need to use it. Synchronisation in UFT usually comes from the need to identify an object before acting upon it. Sync is useful in cases where an object in the old state of the application may match the expected object in the new state of the application. Usually `Sync` is added to tests ad-hoc when it fails due to synchronisation issues.

Comment: OK, there is no need for Page.Sync if for synchronization you have to wait for controls to appear anyways. However, consider a web page which does not change its contents after some click, but does do a page reload. There, Page.Sync is very useful. I think we agree here.

Comment: But what about SAP apps? There is no async "lazy" page/dialog manipulation in SAP, right? Wouldn´t that mean that the easiest way to synchronize with SAP´s dialog flow would be to simply call .Sync after every "context-changing" interaction? Especially if a button click does'nt have visible consequences, but a server roundtrip. But even for more typical screen context-changing clicks, using .Sync wouldavoid the Need for programming Exist checks or Wait-for-existance loops.

Comment: Because if the SAP Sync comes back, it is guaranteed that the SAP session is now idle, while Web´s Page.Sync cannot guarantee that because of the things one can do in JavaScript to load additional stuff and manipulate the DOM in the background, after the poage has been loaded. Right?

Comment: @TheBlastOne, I have to admit not being very familiar with SapGui, my understanding is that the application can get into a _busy_ state and `Sync` waits for it to stop being busy. Note that after `Sync` returns it means that either the SAP applicaiton is no longer busy **or** the timeout has passed (the documentation seems to be a bit misleading, the default timeout is not 0 milliseconds).

Comment: @TheBlastOne, I've rolled back your edit to my answer since it's an answer on to itself. Please add it as an additional answer (there's nothing wrong with answering your own question). Please feel free to accept your answer instead of mine.

Comment: Here's the text you wrote so you don't have to rewrite it :)

So SAP´s Sync works just as Web´s Sync, but one important difference is: While Page.Sync is often no guarantee that the app really is idle when Page.Sync Returns, for SAP applications, SAPSession.Sync´s returning does indeed guarantee this. 

So whenever the SAP Client is doing Server roundtrips, SAPSession.Sync is a very save way of obtaining synchronization (i.e. awaiting SAP client´s idle state).